# How to make playhead / transport / cursor return to start position in Blender?

Tags: blend-files, 3d-cursor

Like DAW does? I need this to be able to test animation comfortably. Or how do you do this?
[image]

Comment: @vklidu please post it as the answer and I'll mark it. Thanks a lot, that is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop animation and move playhead to a frame you start from?
Use just <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: I would like to start from 400th and then when I press stop - it jumps back to 400th

Comment: Use the escape key, as vklidu suggested.